# Building a Django Q object for query

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue wrapping my head how to build a `Q` query in Django while setting it up as a dict.

For example: I have a list of pks for properties and I am trying to filter and see if those pks are associated with either item = `['6', '21', '8', '13', '7', '11', '10', '15', '22']`

I am trying to build a Q object that states:

`Q('accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in' = properties) | Q('journal_line_item__property__pk__in' = properties)` while defining it in a dict I can pass to the queryset like so:

If I define a filter dict and then create values it looks like this but it doesn't create the `Q`:

```
filter_dict = {}
filter_dict['accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in'] = properties
filter_dict['journal_line_item__property__pk__in'] = properties
queryset = queryset.select_related('accounts_payable_line_item', 'journal_line_item').filter(**filter_dict).order_by('-id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass it as named parameter, so:

```
Q(accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in=properties) | Q(
    journal_line_item__property__pk__in=properties
)
```

or as 2-tuples with a string and value:

```
Q(('accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in', properties)) | Q(
    ('journal_line_item__property__pk__in', properties)
)
```

you can also define the `_connector` and thus construct this through one `Q` call:

```
Q(
    accounts_payable_line_item__property__pk__in=properties,
    journal_line_item__property__pk__in=properties,
    _connector=Q.OR,
)
```

Comment: But that doesn't allow something like : `.filter(**filter_dict)`

Comment: @ViaTech: you construct the `q` object and filter with `.filter(my_q_obj)`

Comment: Well, booyah, as usual you're awesome! Appreciate it! I ended up passing all Q items I create for the filter into a list `q_items = list()` (I only showed 1 filter needed here) and then `.filter(*q_items)`